# Hints on analyzing the stacktrace via the example of NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I have the following code. After compilation I delete the MyClassToLoad.class file and run the code.

```
public class ClassLoadersTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClassToLoad c = new MyClassToLoad();
    }
}
```

I get the following stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   classloaders/MyClassToLoad    at
>   classloaders.ClassLoadersTest.main(ClassLoadersTest.java:9)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   classloaders.MyClassToLoad    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
>   ... 6
>   more

As far as I understand, this stacktrace means that there was a ClassNotFoundException, that was caught and rethrown as a NoClassDefFoundError.

The questions are:

1) How can I understand at which line the rethrow happened?

2) Who cuts the stacktrace with "... 6 more" - Java or Idea? How can I see it full?

3) As far as I understand to force the rethrown exception contain the full stacktrace we need to rethrow it as

```
throw new SomeRethrownException("some text", exceptionWhichIsTheReason)
```

But the NoClassDefFoundError doesn't have such a constructor. So in fact it shouldn't print the full stacktrace.. or may be they just put it as Error message as a String?

Comment: The "... 6 more" entries in the ClassNotFoundException stack trace are exactly the six entries in the NoClassDefFoundError trace.

Comment: Stuart, it is ALWAYS like this?

Comment: Generally yes, the truncated entries are usually the same as those of the enclosing exception. See [Throwable.printStackTrace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `classloaders.ClassLoadersTest.main(ClassLoadersTest.java:9) at` <-- here
2. The runtime system. Try

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
       MyClassToLoad c = new MyClassToLoad();
     } catch (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErro e) {
       e.getCause().printStackTrace();
     }
   }
   ```

As for 3, see my answer to 2.

Comment: Elliot, at line 9 there is a line "MyClassToLoad c = new MyClassToLoad()". There are no rethrowal. Looks like I cannot know the exact line?

Comment: By runtime system you mean Idea?

Comment: @Dymytry That is the exact line. You deleted the .class file and that's the first line that causes the ClassLoader to try and resolve the class and invoke the `MyClassToLoad` constructor. By runtime system I mean java.

Comment: Elliot, I mean the line where "throw new NoClassDefFoundError()" is written.

Comment: @Dymytry It's going to likely be in the C++ native code that implements Java. You'll need to get the JDK source to find it.